# HTML5 error, does anyone know what it means?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am using HTML5 and in the process of validating, this error is throughout my pages. I am using PHP within my code as well, I don't know if this is causing the error. The error is:

> Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context

Here is one DIV that brings up this error:

```
<div class="signin">
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])){

echo"
<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";}

else{ echo "
<li><a href='signin.php'>Sign in</a></li>
<li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>
  ";}?>
</div>
```

And here is another:

```
    <div class="navigation">


<li class="navbutton <?php if($navsection == 'home') {echo ' current';}?>" id="navbuttonleft" >
  <a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

    <li class="navbutton  <?php if($navsection == 'products') {echo ' current';}?>">
      <a href="products.php?main=go">Products</a></li>

          <li class="navbutton" <?php echo ($navsection == 'myaccount') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?>>
          <a href="myaccount.php">My Account</a></li>

             <li class="navbutton" <?php echo ($navsection == 'about') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?>>
             <a href="aboutus.php">About us</a></li>

                 <li class="navbutton" <?php echo ($navsection == 'contact') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?>>
                  <a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>

                        <li class="navbutton" <?php echo ($navsection == 'sitemap') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?>>
                          <a href="sitemap.php">Site Map</a></li>



</div>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: how is this question related to html5?

Comment: I am using HTML5 and validating, I felt the issue was related to HTML5 as I have never validated it before, only XHTML.

Comment: how is this question related to php?

Comment: As I use php in my code I was unsure if this was causing my error which I know now it wasn't. So I felt it could be PHP related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML (even HTML5) follows rules by which the elements may be nested to structure your document semantically. In your case, the error means you forgot to wrap the `<li>` elements into a `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>` element, e.g. you forgot to denote beginning and end of a list.

Quoting http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-li-element

> #### 4.3.5.9 The li element
>
> The li element represents a list item.
>
> **Start tag:** required
> **End tag:** optional
> **Categories:** None.
> **Contained By:**
>
> - Inside ol elements.
> - Inside ul elements.
> - Inside menu elements.
>
> **Content Model:** Flow content.

#### Example

```
<ul>
   <li>Unordered First Item with Ordered Sublist
       <ol>
           <li>Ordered First Item</li>
           <li>Ordered Second Item</li>
           <li>Ordered Third Item</li>
       </ol>
   <li>Unordered Second Item</li>
   <li>Unordered Third Item</li>
</ul>
```

#### Output

- Unordered First Item with Ordered Sublist

  1. Ordered First Item
  2. Ordered Second Item
  3. Ordered Third Item

  Unordered Second Item

  Unordered Third Item

Answer (score 1):

you can't have li as a child element of div. it always needs to be inside either `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: That is correct, for some reason way back I deleted the <ul> tags because they were pushing my <li> elements around, and in some case I used php include for code within <ul> tags and deleted them from the HTML by mistake. Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

I think LI should be within an UL or an OL tag

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I made a really silly mistake that I could't see myself after staring at the code for 20 minutes :(

Answer (score 1):

As said before: `<li>` should ALWAYS be embedded into `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags!
Try this:

```
<div class="signin">
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])){

echo"
<ul><li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li></ul>";}

else{ echo "
<ul>
  <li><a href='signin.php'>Sign in</a></li>
  <li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>
</ul>
  ";}?>
</div>
```

And the other one:

```
< nav class = "navigation" >
  <ul>
    < li class = "navbutton <?php if($navsection == 'home') {echo ' current';}?>"
id = "navbuttonleft" > < a href = "index.php" > Home < /a></li >

    < li class = "navbutton  <?php if($navsection == 'products') {echo ' current';}?>" > < a href = "products.php?main=go" > Products < /a></li >

    < li class = "navbutton" < ? php echo($navsection == 'myaccount') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ? >> < a href = "myaccount.php" > My Account < /a></li >

    < li class = "navbutton" < ? php echo($navsection == 'about') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ? >> < a href = "aboutus.php" > About us < /a></li >

    < li class = "navbutton" < ? php echo($navsection == 'contact') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ? >> < a href = "contactus.php" > Contact Us < /a></li >

    < li class = "navbutton" < ? php echo($navsection == 'sitemap') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ? >> < a href = "sitemap.php" > Site Map < /a></li >
  </ul>
< /nav>​
```

Note that I changed your 'div' to 'nav', because this is the preferred element to use in HTML5 for navigation blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will certainly change my code, I do want to do everything correctly and make do the best job I can, thanks!